# zsh and COLUMNS

Tags: terminal, zsh, columns

I cannot understand the behavior of the `$COLUMNS` variable under `zsh`.  Here's an example of the sort of behavior I'm referring to.  The script `$HOME/cols.sh` is the following:

```
echo "COLUMNS=$COLUMNS"
set | grep -a COLUMNS
COLUMNS=
echo "COLUMNS=$COLUMNS"
set | grep -a COLUMNS
```

I get different results depending on whether I run this script with `env -i zsh` or `env -i =zsh`:

```
% env -i zsh -flc '. ~/cols.sh'
COLUMNS=80
COLUMNS=80
COLUMNS=0
COLUMNS=0

% env -i =zsh -flc '. ~/cols.sh'
COLUMNS=80
COLUMNS=80
COLUMNS=80
COLUMNS=80
```

I'm puzzled by

1. The fact that using `zsh` and `=zsh` lead to different results;
2. The fact that, in the first case, setting `COLUMNS=` seems to be equivalent to setting `COLUMNS=0`;
3. The fact that, in the second case, setting `COLUMNS=` seems to have no effect whatsoever;

The docs do not shed much light on these questions:

```
COLUMNS <S>
       The number of columns for this terminal session.  Used for printing select lists and
       for the line editor.
```

FWIW,

```
% which zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
% echo =zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
% =zsh --version
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2)
```

Comment: What `zsh` is run on `env -i zsh` where `PATH` is unset? According to `execvp(3)`, the default PATH is `/usr/bin:/bin`, so it must be a different `zsh` you get.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: Thanks!  That certainly takes care of (1).  (BTW, this is the reason for my other question, about finding the path the currently-running zsh.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Stéphane Chazelas has explained in a comment, `zsh` and `=zsh` give different results because you have two zsh versions in different directories. With `env -i zsh`, `env` looks up `zsh` with `PATH` unset, so it only looks in `/usr/bin` and `/bin` (the [fallback path](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/execvp.3.html)) and executes `/usr/bin/zsh`. With `env -i =zsh`, the instance of zsh that is executing the `env` command [expands `=zsh`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#g_t_0060_003d_0027-expansion) to its full path for the current search path (the current value of `PATH`), which is `/usr/local/bin/zsh`.

The difference in behavior comes from [commit 9af1cd47229041fda4dc07f0ef70691a64d49908](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/9af1cd47229041fda4dc07f0ef70691a64d49908), and more specifically [patch 30533](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2012/msg00455.html), which went in just before zsh 5.0.0 was released. (I found the commit by searching `COLUMNS` in the commit history and confirmed experimentally that this commit makes the difference.)

`COLUMNS` is a “magic” variable that is always updated to the current terminal width. In zsh up to 4.x, settings `COLUMNS` attempts to resize the terminal, but this had never worked correctly, and the code for this was removed in zsh 5.0.0. Hence, in modern versions of zsh, setting `COLUMNS` in an interactive shell has no effect: it's immediately updated back to the terminal width. In older versions, setting a non-numerical value such has the empty string has the same effect as setting the variable to 0, because the value has to be an integer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what is happening.

First, COLUMNS, as you may know, is a variable that tells the width of the terminal screen.  Sometimes the shell sets it for you, so setting it `COLUMNS=` can get the shell to update the value to the actual number of columns in the terminal that it detects.

Second, this command runs a zsh and processes the script:

```
env -i zsh -flc '. ~/cols.sh'
```

Third, this command runs a different shell (either the same one from which it is executed, or the value of $SHELL, I believe), and then processes it; the `=zsh` is pretty much ignored:

```
env -i =zsh -flc '. ~/cols.sh'
```

Actually, this makes it look like the `=zsh` may actually have an effect, but I can't see how that would be useful as I don't believe any shell supports an "empty" environment variable name:

```
env -i =zsh env
```

The output is `=zsh`, which implies there is a variable with no name set to `zsh`.

Comment: `=cmd` is a zsh operator that expands to the path of `cmd`. Similar to `"$(command -v cmd)"` in other shells, except that it's a glob operator, so it's a fatal error if it doesn't match.

Comment: Interesting - how is that different than just running `cmd` out of the path?  Or does it also replace that path with the results of running the cmd, similar to `$(cmd)`?

Comment: in this case, the only difference will be the `argv[0]` `zsh` receives (`zsh` vs `/bin/zsh` with `=zsh`). (note that I cannot reproduce the OP's "1" issue even with the same version of `zsh`). The `=cmd` feature is useful in `ls -l =zsh`, `vi =myscript`...